# Remove Duplicates from DropDownList that is data bound in FormView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, webforms

C# --- ASP.Net WebForm using FormView Control

My issue is I am using a FormView to allow a user to edit some fields in the database. One of those fields already has a value of yes or no. I am allowing the user to change the value to yes if it is no and no if it was yes. I do this by adding List Values of 1. ------Select Yes or No-----, 2. yes and 3. no. Keep in mind the page will load with a value from the database of yes or no. It would be awesome if I could provide a user with only the option to select as yes if the value in the database is no. Or, only provide the option to select no if the value is yes coming from the database. That sounds a bit more complicated that removing duplicate displaying values from the drop down list. I have the following in my manual list of options 91. ------Select Yes or No-----, 2. yes and 3. no) but I also have the value displaying in the list. This makes it look like I have a duplicate of yes or a duplicate of no. I tried some code I saw that would remove the displaying of dupes but I can't get the errors out of it. I will provide below. I hope I have explained this correctly.

ASPX Page

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("New_or_exisitng") %>'      AppendDataBoundItems="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="New_or_exisitng" DataValueField="New_or_exisitng">
                                <asp:ListItem>Select</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>New</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Back-Filled</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

Code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e, object DropDownList1)
    {
        DropDownList MyTextBox = (DropDownList)FormView1.FindControl("DropDownList1");
        if (!DropDownList1.Items.Contains(new ListItem(data)))
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(data);
        }
    }
```

I get an error on items and (data)))

Comment: I also tried this:

Comment: Gee, in place of all these yes, no, maybe, I am not sure and a complex drop down? Why not just place a a check box. They then can only click on it to change from yes to no, and you save world poverty in terms of the code required.

Comment: I will try that @Albert D. Kallal

Comment: The issue is you will still have the previous value displayed. The entire purpose of this feature is to allow a user to change an incorrect value but they would need to see the value to determine if it is incorrect.

Comment: What happens when user wants to revert the choice he/she has made? If existing value is `yes` and it's only `no` available as the only choice, and once user selects `no` there is no way user can go back to `yes` without saving `no` and reloading the page. It's the user experience you want?

Comment: That is correct Chetan Ranpariya. I did my best to convince the user group that we are trying to build for the 1%. They insist someone will make mistakes during the initial entry and the field has to be capable of being changed.

Comment: Can you share the code which is binding data to form view?

Answer (score 0):

This would have been painfully difficult to some in the UI. Instead I developed additional tables in the database to solve the issue. I created a (Code Table) with all of the values that a user would need to select.

id  Typeid  Name    Desc    Createddate
1   1   yes yes 2020-10-25 08:22:59.7233333
2   1   no  no  2020-10-25 08:23:12.5300000
3   2   New New 2020-10-25 08:24:26.4766667
4   2   Back-Filled Back-Filled 2020-10-25 08:24:55.0233333
5   3   Layoff  Layoff  2020-10-25 08:25:38.4600000
6   3   Turnover    Turnover    2020-10-25 08:26:05.1133333

I then used Text with Bind in the DropDownList so that the value would always display first that was previously submitted in the database.
Text='<%# Bind("New_or_exisitng") %>'

I did not use AppendDataBoundItems. Not needed in this Use Case.
Using the database approach I also have no need for an item list as those values come from the table. Below is the complete DropDOwnList. There is no Code Behind.

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("New_or_exisitng") %>'  DataSourceID="NewBackfilled" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Name">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="NewBackfilled" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EchoConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Name] FROM [Codes] WHERE ([Typeid] = @Typeid)">

<asp:Parameter DefaultValue="2" Name="Typeid" Type="Int32" />

</asp:SqlDataSource>